# Angularjs for normal multi paged web application

Tags: php, angularjs

Our team is implementing angular currently and the intention was because a lot of the front end was process driven e.g. lots of user interaction and dynamics with input elements and visual elements.

I am wondering is it considered bad practice to serve pages through a php framework such as laravel normally but have angular on some pages that require more than what html and jquery can give?

All over the web I keep seeing angular used solely for single page applications where the ngRoute kicks in and serves pages that way, however mine is a mix of static content / individual processes and I want the best of both worlds and don't want to have my whole frontend as an angular app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just my personal view:

I think use angular for partial interactions or mix with "normal" pages is not bad practice. But you lost most of benefits. Angular give (me) ability to interact with GUI as it should be and it's simplified front-end and back-end development. Further, I think there are other component-driven libraries which fit better for you use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anton, I am still using the gui and the directives and http the only thing I'm not doing is actioning my controllers based on URL rather I am creating each page like it is a one page app.

Comment: If your users, team members and you are happy with this approach - why not? It's ok. But it's hard for me to imagine why not use angular for whole front-end work (I'm little bit fanatical of angular 1.x). ngRoute isn't the best, but ui-router is ok.

Comment: thanks, I will have a think about it and see what our app would function like if it was all angular driven.